# How to define an object in the header file and initialize it in the source file

Tags: c++, header-files

I have an object `qp` that is defined as

```cpp
#include <proxsuite/proxqp/dense/dense.hpp>

namespace fr3_ros {

class WaypointController : public controller_interface::MultiInterfaceController<franka_hw::FrankaModelInterface, 
                                                                                 hardware_interface::EffortJointInterface, 
                                                                                 franka_hw::FrankaStateInterface> {
...

private:
  proxsuite::proxqp::isize dim = 14;
  proxsuite::proxqp::isize n_eq = 7;
  proxsuite::proxqp::isize n_in = 0;
  proxsuite::proxqp::dense::QP<double> qp(dim, n_eq, n_in);

...
}
```

From the documetation [here](http://docs.ros.org/en/jade/api/controller_interface/html/c++/classcontroller__interface_1_1MultiInterfaceController.html#a447670cd5df560f7066282e5fd09092b) `controller_interface::MultiInterfaceController` has the constructor

```cpp
MultiInterfaceController (bool allow_optional_interfaces=false)
```

Since I did not define a new constructor, that would be the only constructor `WaypointController` has.

However, if I put this in the header file it would give me an error when compiling:

```
In file included from /home/bolun/bolun_ws/src/fr3_ros/fr3_ros/src/waypoint_controller.cpp:1:
/home/bolun/bolun_ws/src/fr3_ros/fr3_ros/include/fr3_ros/waypoint_controller.h:113:43: error: ‘dim’ is not a type
  113 |   proxsuite::proxqp::dense::QP<double> qp(dim, n_eq, n_in);
      |                                           ^~~
/home/bolun/bolun_ws/src/fr3_ros/fr3_ros/include/fr3_ros/waypoint_controller.h:113:48: error: ‘n_eq’ is not a type
  113 |   proxsuite::proxqp::dense::QP<double> qp(dim, n_eq, n_in);
      |                                                ^~~~
/home/bolun/bolun_ws/src/fr3_ros/fr3_ros/include/fr3_ros/waypoint_controller.h:113:54: error: ‘n_in’ is not a type
  113 |   proxsuite::proxqp::dense::QP<double> qp(dim, n_eq, n_in);
      |                                                      ^~~~
/home/bolun/bolun_ws/src/fr3_ros/fr3_ros/src/waypoint_controller.cpp: In member function ‘virtual void fr3_ros::WaypointController::update(const ros::Time&, const ros::Duration&)’:
/home/bolun/bolun_ws/src/fr3_ros/fr3_ros/src/waypoint_controller.cpp:225:5: error: invalid use of member function ‘proxsuite::proxqp::dense::QP<double> fr3_ros::WaypointController::qp(int, int, int)’ (did you forget the ‘()’ ?)
  225 |     qp.update(qp_H, qp_g, qp_A, qp_b, std::nullopt, std::nullopt, std::nullopt);
      |     ^~
/home/bolun/bolun_ws/src/fr3_ros/fr3_ros/src/waypoint_controller.cpp:227:5: error: invalid use of member function ‘proxsuite::proxqp::dense::QP<double> fr3_ros::WaypointController::qp(int, int, int)’ (did you forget the ‘()’ ?)
  227 |     qp.init(qp_H, qp_g, qp_A, qp_b, std::nullopt, std::nullopt, std::nullopt);
      |     ^~
/home/bolun/bolun_ws/src/fr3_ros/fr3_ros/src/waypoint_controller.cpp:230:3: error: invalid use of member function ‘proxsuite::proxqp::dense::QP<double> fr3_ros::WaypointController::qp(int, int, int)’ (did you forget the ‘()’ ?)
  230 |   qp.solve();
      |   ^~
/home/bolun/bolun_ws/src/fr3_ros/fr3_ros/src/waypoint_controller.cpp:232:13: error: invalid use of member function ‘proxsuite::proxqp::dense::QP<double> fr3_ros::WaypointController::qp(int, int, int)’ (did you forget the ‘()’ ?)
  232 |   torques = qp.results.x.bottomLeftCorner(7, 1);
      |             ^~
```

I also tried separating the declaration and definition, in the header file I have

```cpp
proxsuite::proxqp::isize dim = 14;
proxsuite::proxqp::isize n_eq = 7;
proxsuite::proxqp::isize n_in = 0;
proxsuite::proxqp::dense::QP<double> qp;
```

and in the source file I have

```cpp
qp = proxsuite::proxqp::dense::QP<double>(dim, n_eq, n_in);
```

this gives me another error

```
In file included from /opt/ros/noetic/include/class_loader/class_loader_core.hpp:45,
                 from /opt/ros/noetic/include/class_loader/class_loader.hpp:46,
                 from /opt/ros/noetic/include/pluginlib/class_list_macros.hpp:40,
                 from /opt/ros/noetic/include/pluginlib/class_list_macros.h:35,
                 from /home/bolun/bolun_ws/src/fr3_ros/fr3_ros/src/waypoint_controller.cpp:13:
/opt/ros/noetic/include/class_loader/meta_object.hpp: In instantiation of ‘B* class_loader::impl::MetaObject<C, B>::create() const [with C = fr3_ros::WaypointController; B = controller_interface::ControllerBase]’:
/opt/ros/noetic/include/class_loader/meta_object.hpp:196:7:   required from here
/opt/ros/noetic/include/class_loader/meta_object.hpp:198:12: error: use of deleted function ‘fr3_ros::WaypointController::WaypointController()’
  198 |     return new C;
      |            ^~~~~
In file included from /home/bolun/bolun_ws/src/fr3_ros/fr3_ros/src/waypoint_controller.cpp:1:
/home/bolun/bolun_ws/src/fr3_ros/fr3_ros/include/fr3_ros/waypoint_controller.h:36:7: note: ‘fr3_ros::WaypointController::WaypointController()’ is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
   36 | class WaypointController : public controller_interface::MultiInterfaceController<franka_hw::FrankaModelInterface,
      |       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/bolun/bolun_ws/src/fr3_ros/fr3_ros/include/fr3_ros/waypoint_controller.h:36:7: error: no matching function for call to ‘proxsuite::proxqp::dense::QP<double>::QP()’
In file included from /home/bolun/miniconda3/envs/fr3_env/include/proxsuite/proxqp/dense/dense.hpp:8,
                 from /home/bolun/bolun_ws/src/fr3_ros/fr3_ros/include/fr3_ros/waypoint_controller.h:31,
                 from /home/bolun/bolun_ws/src/fr3_ros/fr3_ros/src/waypoint_controller.cpp:1:
/home/bolun/miniconda3/envs/fr3_env/include/proxsuite/proxqp/dense/wrapper.hpp:94:3: note: candidate: ‘proxsuite::proxqp::dense::QP<T>::QP(proxsuite::linalg::veg::isize, proxsuite::linalg::veg::isize, proxsuite::linalg::veg::isize) [with T = double; proxsuite::linalg::veg::isize = long int]’
   94 |   QP(isize _dim, isize _n_eq, isize _n_in)
      |   ^~
/home/bolun/miniconda3/envs/fr3_env/include/proxsuite/proxqp/dense/wrapper.hpp:94:3: note:   candidate expects 3 arguments, 0 provided
/home/bolun/miniconda3/envs/fr3_env/include/proxsuite/proxqp/dense/wrapper.hpp:81:8: note: candidate: ‘proxsuite::proxqp::dense::QP<double>::QP(const proxsuite::proxqp::dense::QP<double>&)’
   81 | struct QP
      |        ^~
/home/bolun/miniconda3/envs/fr3_env/include/proxsuite/proxqp/dense/wrapper.hpp:81:8: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
/home/bolun/miniconda3/envs/fr3_env/include/proxsuite/proxqp/dense/wrapper.hpp:81:8: note: candidate: ‘proxsuite::proxqp::dense::QP<double>::QP(proxsuite::proxqp::dense::QP<double>&&)’
/home/bolun/miniconda3/envs/fr3_env/include/proxsuite/proxqp/dense/wrapper.hpp:81:8: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
```

If I add `extern` in the header file, I get the error

```
In file included from /home/bolun/bolun_ws/src/fr3_ros/fr3_ros/src/waypoint_controller.cpp:1:
/home/bolun/bolun_ws/src/fr3_ros/fr3_ros/include/fr3_ros/waypoint_controller.h:113:3: error: storage class specified for ‘qp’
  113 |   extern proxsuite::proxqp::dense::QP<double> qp;
      |   ^~~~~~
In file included from /opt/ros/noetic/include/class_loader/class_loader_core.hpp:45,
                 from /opt/ros/noetic/include/class_loader/class_loader.hpp:46,
                 from /opt/ros/noetic/include/pluginlib/class_list_macros.hpp:40,
                 from /opt/ros/noetic/include/pluginlib/class_list_macros.h:35,
                 from /home/bolun/bolun_ws/src/fr3_ros/fr3_ros/src/waypoint_controller.cpp:13:
/opt/ros/noetic/include/class_loader/meta_object.hpp: In instantiation of ‘B* class_loader::impl::MetaObject<C, B>::create() const [with C = fr3_ros::WaypointController; B = controller_interface::ControllerBase]’:
/opt/ros/noetic/include/class_loader/meta_object.hpp:196:7:   required from here
/opt/ros/noetic/include/class_loader/meta_object.hpp:198:12: error: use of deleted function ‘fr3_ros::WaypointController::WaypointController()’
  198 |     return new C;
      |            ^~~~~
In file included from /home/bolun/bolun_ws/src/fr3_ros/fr3_ros/src/waypoint_controller.cpp:1:
/home/bolun/bolun_ws/src/fr3_ros/fr3_ros/include/fr3_ros/waypoint_controller.h:36:7: note: ‘fr3_ros::WaypointController::WaypointController()’ is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
   36 | class WaypointController : public controller_interface::MultiInterfaceController<franka_hw::FrankaModelInterface,
      |       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/bolun/bolun_ws/src/fr3_ros/fr3_ros/include/fr3_ros/waypoint_controller.h:36:7: error: no matching function for call to ‘proxsuite::proxqp::dense::QP<double>::QP()’
In file included from /home/bolun/miniconda3/envs/fr3_env/include/proxsuite/proxqp/dense/dense.hpp:8,
                 from /home/bolun/bolun_ws/src/fr3_ros/fr3_ros/include/fr3_ros/waypoint_controller.h:31,
                 from /home/bolun/bolun_ws/src/fr3_ros/fr3_ros/src/waypoint_controller.cpp:1:
/home/bolun/miniconda3/envs/fr3_env/include/proxsuite/proxqp/dense/wrapper.hpp:94:3: note: candidate: ‘proxsuite::proxqp::dense::QP<T>::QP(proxsuite::linalg::veg::isize, proxsuite::linalg::veg::isize, proxsuite::linalg::veg::isize) [with T = double; proxsuite::linalg::veg::isize = long int]’
   94 |   QP(isize _dim, isize _n_eq, isize _n_in)
      |   ^~
/home/bolun/miniconda3/envs/fr3_env/include/proxsuite/proxqp/dense/wrapper.hpp:94:3: note:   candidate expects 3 arguments, 0 provided
/home/bolun/miniconda3/envs/fr3_env/include/proxsuite/proxqp/dense/wrapper.hpp:81:8: note: candidate: ‘proxsuite::proxqp::dense::QP<double>::QP(const proxsuite::proxqp::dense::QP<double>&)’
   81 | struct QP
      |        ^~
/home/bolun/miniconda3/envs/fr3_env/include/proxsuite/proxqp/dense/wrapper.hpp:81:8: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
/home/bolun/miniconda3/envs/fr3_env/include/proxsuite/proxqp/dense/wrapper.hpp:81:8: note: candidate: ‘proxsuite::proxqp::dense::QP<double>::QP(proxsuite::proxqp::dense::QP<double>&&)’
/home/bolun/miniconda3/envs/fr3_env/include/proxsuite/proxqp/dense/wrapper.hpp:81:8: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
```

Is it possible for someone to help me understand what is the issue here? Is the a universal issue in C++ or is it just this package?

Thanks in advance!

If I were to intialize qp using a member initialize list, should it look like:

```cpp
public:
  WaypointController()
      : dim(14), neq(7), n_in(0), qp(dim, n_eq, n_in) 
  {
  }
```

Comment: Don't *define* variables in header files. That will make them defined in all [translation units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)) which have included that header file, and break the one definition rule. Only *declare* in header file, and define in source file.

Comment: Better still, don't have global variables at all. Especially in the global top namespace.

Comment: I also tried that, and it does not work. I think the error in the first case is that the compiler thinks I am defining a function.

Comment: You can't have general statements (like your assignment statement) outside of functions.

Comment: I don't understand, I think what I am doing is that I created the object `qp` and initializes it with `proxsuite::proxqp::dense::QP<double>(dim, n_eq, n_in)`.

Comment: Re: "Since I did not define a new constructor, that would be the only constructor `WaypointController` has"` -- no, constructors are not inherited. It will have a default constructor, a copy constructor, and a move constructor, because that's what the compiler does with **any** class that doesn't have an explicit constructor.

Comment: @PeteBecker I see. If I call the default constructor, will the constructor of the parent class also be called?

Comment: @QualsPassed -- the compiler-generated default constructor will call the base class's default constructor. `MultiInterfaceController (bool allow_optional_interfaces=false)` can be called with no arguments (using the default value for the argument), so it is a default constructor.

Answer (score 0):

The error message you're getting is not particularly helpful here, but let me explain it anyways, so you understand what's going on.

C++ believes that you're trying to declare a *function*, not define a variable.

```
proxsuite::proxqp::dense::QP<double> qp(dim, n_eq, n_in);
```

The return type is `proxsuite::proxqp::dense::QP<double>`, the function's name is `qp`, and it takes 3 parameters, of types `dim`, `n_eq`, and `n_in`.

The fact that this is not what you intended in entirely irrelevant.

Knowing this, your error messages make a lot more sense.

The solution to this is to declare the field in the header file, like so:

```
proxsuite::proxqp::dense::QP<double> qp;
```

And then to you need to initialize `qp` in your constructor. Use a member initialization list for this.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249760/discussion-on-answer-by-coffeetableespresso-how-to-define-an-object-in-the-heade).